# Zend Database get count

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework

I have a query to count all rows in Db table.

```
$results = $db->fetchAll('select count(id) as total_keys, sum(if(used,1,0)) as used_keys from product_keys');
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($results);
```

I want to get the total_keys and used_keys, but it doesn't seen to work.

Comment: How is your database table? What fields? maybe you can change your query

Comment: it work when I try it in cmd. getting some values from total keys and used keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$results = $db->fetchOne('select count(id) as total_keys, sum(if(used,1,0)) as used_keys from product_keys');
$this->_helper->flashMessenger->addMessage($results);
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but only getting the total keys. how come the used keys doesn't show?